# Framed paragraph with double-line frame

Tags: boxes, mdframed, framed

Regarding various ways but most requires rigorous settings to embed a paragraph of words in a box or a frame with double-line box, I try to use a single commend to acquire the effect.

[image]

However, just as the picture has shown, the "doublebox" command in fancybox fails to wrap the words into paragraph. As for the "framed" command, it doesn't provide a "double-line" frame but actually wraps the paragraph instead.

Is there another command or a slight modification to the current code to warp a paragraph into a doubled-line frame(box)?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancybox,framed}
\begin{document}
\doublebox{Over the past twenty years, the study of industrial organization—the analysis of imperfectly competitive markets—has grown from a niche area of microeconomics to a key component of economics.}\\

\begin{framed}
Over the past twenty years, the study of industrial organization—the analysis of imperfectly competitive markets—has grown from a niche area of microeconomics to a key component of economics. 
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, but you can make one easily enough using \doublebox and \parbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancybox,framed}
\begin{document}
\doublebox{%
\begin{minipage}{4in}
Over the past twenty years, the study of industrial organization—the analysis of imperfectly competitive markets—has grown from a niche area of microeconomics to a key component of economics.
\end{minipage}}\\
\begin{framed}
Over the past twenty years, the study of industrial organization—the analysis of imperfectly competitive markets—has grown from a niche area of microeconomics to a key component of economics. 
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image: doublebox]

Answer (score 10):

Here's a `tcolorbox` version (with 'minimal' options) and some example of usages

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcolorbox{tcbdoublebox}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  sharp corners,
  colback=white,
  borderline={1pt}{-2pt}{black},
  fontupper={\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}},
  #1
}
\begin{document}


%\doublebox{Over the past twenty years, the study of industrial organization—the analysis of imperfectly competitive markets—has grown from a niche area of microeconomics to a key component of economics.}\\

\begin{tcbdoublebox}
Over the past twenty years, the study of industrial organization—the analysis of imperfectly competitive markets has grown from a niche area of microeconomics to a key component of economics. 
\end{tcbdoublebox}


\begin{tcbdoublebox}[drop shadow]
Over the past twenty years, the study of industrial organization—the analysis of imperfectly competitive markets has grown from a niche area of microeconomics to a key component of economics. 
\end{tcbdoublebox}


\begin{tcbdoublebox}[title={With a title}]
Over the past twenty years, the study of industrial organization—the analysis of imperfectly competitive markets has grown from a niche area of microeconomics to a key component of economics. 
\end{tcbdoublebox}

\begin{tcbdoublebox}[colback={white!40!yellow}]
Over the past twenty years, the study of industrial organization—the analysis of imperfectly competitive markets has grown from a niche area of microeconomics to a key component of economics. 
\end{tcbdoublebox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make the inner frame line-width thinner?

Comment: @Howard: `boxrule=0.5pt` (for example)

Comment: @Howard: Why this `acceptance hopping` -- this is not really kosher!

Comment: The first one did it with only a "slight modification" which answered the question. But your alternative solution provides customization to handle various situations which I think its more useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do I remove indentation inside the box?

Comment: (to remove the first line indent there's [tcolorbox - Remove indentation in double-line frame - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537120/remove-indentation-in-double-line-frame))