# Remove indentation in double-line frame

Tags: tcolorbox

Currently doing a template for exam and I have to box the text to grab attention from students.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcolorbox{tcbdoublebox}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  sharp corners,
  colback=white,
  borderline={1pt}{-2pt}{black},
  fontupper={\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}},
  #1
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcbdoublebox}[width=14cm]
    \textbf{{\ignorespacesafterend Do Not Turn Over This Page Until You Are Told To Do So}}
\end{tcbdoublebox}

\end{document}
```

This shows me the following preview:

[image]

Is that any way to remove the indentation so that the box is nicely shown? Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to typeset your text inside a `hbox` and remove the paragraph indentation you have set for the upper part of the box. The width of the `hbox` is determined by the natural width of the content.

By default the content is typeset inside a minipage-like environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{tcbdoublebox}[1][]{%
    enhanced jigsaw,
    before=\bigskip\centering,
    after=\par\bigskip,
    fontupper=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    hbox,
    colback=white,
    borderline={1pt}{-2pt}{black},
    #1
}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2][2-5]

\begin{tcbdoublebox}%
    Do Not Turn Over This Page Until You Are Told To Do So
\end{tcbdoublebox}

\lipsum[1-2][2-5]

\end{document}
```