# How to insert a margin inside a double frame parbox?

Tags: framed, parbox

I simply would like to insert a bit of space inside my parbox, but the following mess up with the frames:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \fbox{
        \setlength\fboxsep{1cm}
        \fbox{
            \parbox{0.80\textwidth}{
                \textbf{Rules :}
                \vskip 1em%
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item 1st rule: You do not talk about Fight Club.
                    \item 2nd rule: You do not talk about Fight Club.
                    \item 3rd rule: If someone yells "Stop!", ...
                    \item 4th rule: Only two guys to a fight.
                \end{itemize}
            }
        }
    }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've tried to use `mdframed` but the double frame isn't that simple.

Comment: I don't really understand what's wrong with the image that you show?

Comment: the double frames are ugly. The distance between each line is not the same don't the left, right and top part. If you remove the `\setlength\fboxsep{1cm}` it gets fixed, but I don't have the inner margin anymore.

Comment: Do you need to make the double frame or fix your code? For making there's [boxes - Framed paragraph with double-line frame - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305879/framed-paragraph-with-double-line-frame)

Comment: Already tried the `\doublebox{%\begin{minipage}{4in}` but it doesn't really work :(

Comment: [Edit] into question and include error messages/output etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many similar questions, the issue is stray spaces being introduced at open end-of-lines.  The remedy is to remove the stray spaces by adding a `%` after the end-of-line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \fbox{%
        \setlength\fboxsep{1cm}%
        \fbox{%
            \parbox{0.80\textwidth}{%
                \textbf{Rules :}
                \vskip 1em%
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item 1st rule: You do not talk about Fight Club.
                    \item 2nd rule: You do not talk about Fight Club.
                    \item 3rd rule: If someone yells "Stop!", ...
                    \item 4th rule: Only two guys to a fight.
                \end{itemize}
            }%
        }%
    }%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}


\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, sharp corners, center, 
    valign=center, colback=white, boxsep=8mm,
     borderline={.5mm}{3mm}{black},
     width=.85\linewidth,
    ]
                \textbf{Rules:}
                \vskip 1em%
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item 1st rule: You do not talk about Fight Club.
                    \item 2nd rule: You do not talk about Fight Club.
                    \item 3rd rule: If someone yells "Stop!", ...
                    \item 4th rule: Only two guys to a fight.
                \end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]